# Java scanner into a list

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

Unsuccessful to assign input numbers into a list, my code is as follows, which part was wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please input numbers:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
            list.add(input.nextDouble());
        }

    for (p : list){
    System.out.print(p);
    }
    input.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Your compiler is giving you a specific error message and pointing at the exact place where the problem is.

Comment: you are not coming out of while loop.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala Wrong. The while loop itself is fine, but the code won't compile.

Comment: If your code doesn't compile then maybe your compiler has a good reason to do so, always post the exception it gives you because it's the most informative part.

Answer (score 3):

I think the variable 'p' cannot be resolved to a type, its type must be declared before used.

Maybe you can do like this:

```
for (Double p : list){
    System.out.print(p);
}
```